# XPath starts-with function is not working

Tags: php, xml, xpath

Using PHP and XPath, I am trying to use XPath's start-with function to retrieve data from the "name" element in the XML file below. The code below is not retrieving anything. Can anyone advise? Thanks!

```
$xmldoc = simplexml_load_file("products.xml");
$query = $xmldoc->xpath('/products/product[starts-with(name, "Desk")]');  
foreach($query as $Products) {
echo $Products->name . " ";
echo $Products->price . "<br>";
}
```

Here is the XML file (named product.xml):

```
<products>

<product type="Electronics">
<name>Desktop</name>
<price>499.99</price>
<store>Best Buy</store>
</product>

<product type="Hardware">
<name>Hand Saw</name>
<price>99.99</price>
<store>Lowes</store>
</product>

</products>
```

Comment: It [works here](http://codepad.org/KuYdn8E8), You mention both `product.xml` & `products.xml`, are you sure that isn't the issue?

Comment: Is there anything else in the xml? If `<products>` isn't the root tag you need to write `//products/...` in order to select it.